# Restrictions of maps between projective varieties.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, dimension-theory-analysis

Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a surjective algebraic map between two projective $k$-varieties, where $k$ is algebraically closed. Let $n=\dim(X),\,m=\dim(Y)$. Suppose furthermore that X,Y are irreducible. From surjectivity, we have - $n\geq m$. Is it always true that we can find a closed subset $X_0\subset X$ s.t. $\dim(X_0)=m$ and $f|_{X_0}\colon X_0\to Y$ is surjective? If not, under what conditions is it true and can we forget about the irreducibility hypothesis?

Thanks!

Comment: This is an interesting question! Intuitively what you want to do is find a section of $f$ which will be a closed embedding.  Now, there doesn't always exist sections, which makes me doubtful that this is true. Still interestin!

Comment: Thanks! till now, I was kinda using it as a given, and figured it was time to prove or disprove the lemma. About the sections, not necessarily, the main difference here is that the map I'm looking for, need not be injective. This means that it doesn't have to come from a section (as I can map to several points of X from each point of Y).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If $\dim X>\dim Y$, taking $\mathcal{O}(1)$ be a very ample line bundle on $X$,
then in the linear system $|\mathcal{O}(1)|$ there is a  divisor dominates $Y$.**

This is because $|\mathcal{O}(1)|$ intersects the fiber of $f$ non-trivially.

By this, we can cut down the dimension of $X$ and hence get an affirmative answer to your problem.

On the other hand, irreducibility hypothesis is not necessary because we can just take irreducible component, then the problem is reduced to the irreducible case.